# Error: Could not find or load main class Amazon.StartApplication

Tags: java, selenium, appium

Newbie Query, I've included paths/jars properly for appium but still seem to get this above error during debug. Also seen was the unreachable browser exception w.r.t AndroidDriver. Any help is appreciated.

```
package amazon;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class StartApplication {

        private static AndroidDriver driver;
        public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

            File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/Apps/Amazon/");
            File app = new File(appDir, "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping.apk");

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Micromax A311");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping");
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity");

            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Comment: Is your appium server running? Check by hitting `http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub` in your browser.
And instead of `AndroidDriver`, use `AppiumDriver`.
`private static AppiumDriver driver;`

Comment: That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP resource - see this response for the URL, > info: [debug] Responding to client that we did not find a valid resource > and this in the appium application.

Comment: @DanyDP do this two changes it might works......1)Remove private static AndroidDriver driver; 2)add  private static webdriver driver;3)use RemoteWebDriver for url connection .....give a try...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class StartApplication {

        private static AndroidDriver driver=null;
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

            File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/Apps/Amazon/");
            File app = new File(appDir, "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping.apk");

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Micromax A311");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping");
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity");

            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks karthik, the code above resolved most references but the initial issue with main remains, is this relative to the java home/path env variables? (which i added following some threads here)

Comment: To ensure ur path variables are set correctly, go to cmd prompt and hit 'appium'. this should open appium server window

Comment: Yup, it is, but no fruition with the original error.

Comment: AssertionViolatedException [Java Application] 
 org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException at localhost:50475 
  Thread [main] (Suspended (exception AssertionViolatedException)) 
   AssertionViolatedException.main(String[]) line: 104 
 C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (Jan 28, 2016, 6:45:31 PM)

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class Amazon.StartApplication
Along with this original error.

Comment: Have u set JAVA_HOME in ur path variables.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_71 its set to this, should this be jre path instead?

Comment: as per the code pasted above, im guessing i have not.

Comment: That should be the issue , its snot able to find the main function because u have not imported the package name 'package-name;'